# SuiteCRM: Disable TinyMCE editor for the description field

Tags: tinymce, sugarcrm, htmlpurifier

I recently upgraded my Sugar CE to Suite 7.2.

I find that the status description field in the Cases module has TinyMCE editor (which was not the case in Sugar CE).

When I create a new case the html tags appear in the status description field. (please see the attached image.)

[image]

I would prefer to use a simple textarea rather than TinyMCE editor. Is there a way to disable TinyMCE editor?

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer in another form. I tried it and tested it works for me.

As I already mentioned this problem can be solved by disabling the TinyMCE editor for the status description field. Here is how you do it:

1. Edit the file /custom/modules/Cases/views/view.edit.php and comment the line:

   `echo $tiny->getInstance('update_text,description', 'email_compose_light');`
2. Then do a quick repair and rebuild: Go to Admin -> Repair -> choose Quick Repair and Rebuild

After this you should not see TinyMCE editor and when you edit any record you also see that html tags don't appear.